# cannot move out of type `[T; D]`, a non-copy array

Tags: arrays, rust, move, unsafe, maybeuninit

I'm initializing an array using code called through FFI and thus I'm using an array if `MaybeUninit` to represent that data. It looks something like this:

```
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

#[allow(unused)]
fn init_with_ffi<T>(data: &mut [T]) {
    todo!();
}

fn get_array<T, const D: usize>() -> [T; D] {
    let mut my_array: [MaybeUninit<T>; D] = unsafe {
        MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init()
    };
    init_with_ffi(&mut my_array[..]);
    unsafe {
        *(&mut my_array as *mut [MaybeUninit<T>; D] as *mut [T; D])
    }
}
```

This is similar to one of the examples presented in [the docs for MaybeUninit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html) but generic instead. I'm having to use raw pointers here since `std::mem::transmute` does not work with arrays of a generic size.

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0508]: cannot move out of type `[T; D]`, a non-copy array
  --> src/main.rs:14:9
   |
14 |         *(&mut my_array as *mut [MaybeUninit<T>; D] as *mut [T; D])
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         cannot move out of here
   |         move occurs because value has type `[T; D]`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

This error message makes no sense to me. It would make sense if I was trying to copy a non-copy array or if I was trying to move ONE of the values out of a non-copy array. But I'm trying to move the entire array and my impression has always been that this should be possible, no?

Comment: If you can use nightly, you'll have access to [`array_assume_init`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#method.array_assume_init).

Comment: I can also use `my_array.map(|x| x.assume_init())` but my question was more about why the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is effectively the same as:

```rust
let ptr: *mut [T;D] = &mut my_array as *mut [MaybeUninit<T>; D] as *mut [T; D];
*ptr
```

Which would attempt to copy, not move, the data out of the pointer - hence your issue

The usual solution, demonstrated in the [Initializing an array element-by-element](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initializing-an-array-element-by-element) section in the `MaybeUninit` docs, is using `std::mem::transmute` instead, but currently it [does not work with const generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61956).

Instead, you can use [`read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.read) to copy the elements from the `MaybeUninit<T>` array to a new `T` array. In the general case, you would have to worry about duplicating a `T` and dropping the same contents twice, but since `MaybeUninit` doesn't call drop on its containing data when it itself is dropped, it should be safe. Otherwise you can use `std::mem::forget` on the original array to force not calling the drop method.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61956

Comment: Try `ptr.read()` then. It should be safe to copy the array since `MaybeUninit` does not drop the contents when going out of scope.

Comment: @EmilEriksson in fact, that's literally what "horribly error-prone workaround" section in the bug you posted does.

Comment: Yeah, after tons of googling I have learned that one cannot move out of a dereferences pointer just like that it seems, you need to use `ptr::read`. The error messages gives no indication of this and I found it very confusing.

Comment: @EmilEriksson FWIW you can't move out of a normal `&T` reference either. Pointers operate similarly in that regard - you need to use the `read` and `write` methods to use them in a more low-level manner.

Comment: I realize now why that wouldn't even make sense... if you could move out of even a mutable reference, you would leave an invalid value for the owner of the value.

Comment: Prefer `transmute_copy()` to `read()`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I assume `transmute_copy` works because it doesn't care about the potential size difference between `Src` and `Dst` and wouldn't fail in the same way that `transmute` would?

In this case I don't think it would be needed since `MaybeUninit` prevents dropping but otherwise I guess that I would also need to `mem::forget` the old value.